I able to receive GET requests from the webhook but not POST requests
I'm encountering an issue with receiving webhook notifications from both Facebook and Instagram. While I'm able to successfully receive GET requests from the webhook and also receive test messages from Instagram to the same server, POST requests for Facebook page are not reaching but Instagram message reaching my server.
I've checked my server configuration, ensured that the endpoint is configured to accept both GET and POST requests, and verified that the webhook settings in the Facebook Developer Dashboard. Additionally, I have subscribed to receive feed updates for the Facebook Page.

I not get post request from Facebook page webhoook and also I have subscribed to field.
References: page

Check if you're subscribed to "messages" field, and I recommend subscribing through api, in their developer UI some kinds of bugs
